# Why is contactform in reactjs not working?

Tags: php, reactjs

I made a landingspage in reactjs, on this page is a contactform and I tried to send an email with php but it doesn't work. I know that you can't use php in react but I read online that you can do it like this. I think there might be something wrong with the link to the contactform.php. It does show a 404 errormessage, I can see in the console that it puts all the information in the state. But when I click on submit, nothing happends. Anyone who can explain me why?

```
constructor()
{
    super();
    this.state = {
        organisatie: '',
        naam: '',
        email: '',
        telefoon: '',
        vraag: '',
        error: null,
        mailSent: false
    };
}
  handleFormSubmit = e => {
    console.log(this.state);
      e.preventDefault();
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${API_PATH}`,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        data: this.state
      })
        .then(result => {
          this.setState({
            mailSent: result.data.sent
          })
        })
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
    };
```

And form in html:

```
<div className="col-md-6 contactform pl-2">
                        <form action="/contactForm.php">
                        <p>Naam Organisatie / praktijk * </p>
                        <input type="text" id="praktijk" name="organisatie" required="" value={organisatie} onChange={e => this.setState({ organisatie: e.target.value })}/>
                        <p> Uw naam * </p>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="naam" required="" value={naam} onChange={e => this.setState({ naam: e.target.value })}/>
                        <p>Uw e-mailadres * </p>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required="" value={email} onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })} />
                        <p>Uw telefoonnummer * </p>
                        <input type="text" id="telnr" name="telefoon" required="" value={telefoon} onChange={e => this.setState({ telefoon: e.target.value })}/>
                        <p>Vraag / opmerking *</p>
                        <textarea id="bericht" name="vraag" required="" value={vraag} onChange={e => this.setState({ vraag: e.target.value })}> </textarea> <br />
                        <p><input type="checkbox" name="akkoord" value="akkoord" />Ik ga akkoord met de <a href="/algemene-voorwaarden">Algemene voorwaarden</a></p><br />
                        <input type="submit" className="btn-submit mt-3" onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)}/>

                        <div>
                          {this.state.mailSent &&
                            <div>Bedankt voor het invullen van het contactformulier! Er wordt zo snel mogelijk contact met u opgenomen.</div>
                          }
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

And this is what i have in the php file:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

 if (empty($_POST['naam']) && empty($_POST['email'])) die();

if ($_POST)
{

// set response code - 200 OK

http_response_code(200);
$subject = $_POST['naam'];
$to = "knevel.adinda@gmail.com";
$from = $_POST['email'];

// data

$msg = $_POST['telefoon'] . $_POST['vraag'];

// Headers

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers.= "From: <" . $from . ">";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

// echo json_encode( $_POST );

echojson_encode(array(
    "sent" => true
));
}
  else
{

// tell the user about error

echojson_encode(["sent" => false, "message" => "Something went wrong"]);
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way SO works is that you provide as much information as possible to help people help you. You have given us your code, which is good, but you need to provide more information about what didn't work (error messages etc), and ideally narrow down the problem to a particular area in the code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info

Comment: I suggest reviewing the Forms documentation for React components - You might need a helper method like handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: 404 means the resource cannot be found. What is `${API_PATH}` that you are sending to?

Comment: Yeah I know, I used const API_PATH = 'http://yardtheme.test/src/screens/contactform.php; But I tried a lot of different things aswell. I got that from this website: https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-build-a-contact-form-with-react-js-and-php-d5977c17fec0